# How block connect to FTP via TotalCommender and Filezilla

Tags: debian, ftp, filezilla, vps, total-commander

How block connect to FTP via TotalCommender and Filezilla?

I tried via firewall but doesn't work for me.

I use cyberduck and ssh and I have two server (Debian 6 i 7)

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to clarify a few things? Are you trying to block FTP access in general? Or just to these two programs? Or _insecure_ FTP? SFTP is FTP over SSH.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you can block connections for particular programms in Windows by command line prompt or with control panel's gui tools.

Something like this:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Filezilla" dir=out action=block program="C:\filezilla.exe" enable=yes
```